Implementing stripe in ios, causes error in generated swift files? 'Missing return in closure expected to return 'String''
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Missing return in closure expected to return 'String'
/Users/mac/Documents/Programming/Projects/yay_food/ios/Pods/StripeCore/StripeCore/StripeCore/Source/Analytics/AnalyticLoggableError.swift:62:8

Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): Missing return in closure expected to return 'String'
/Users/mac/Documents/Programming/Projects/yay_food/ios/Pods/StripeCore/StripeCore/StripeCore/Source/Analytics/AnalyticLoggableError.swift:69:8

I have searched everywhere but It doesn't seem like a problem regarding swift cause those are self generated files that stripe has generated for ios.
I tried doing flutter clean and restarting everything but that didn't work either.
this is the lines where the error occurred:
public func serializeForV1Analytics() -> [String: Any] {
        let errorType: String = {
            if let analyticLoggableError = self as? AnalyticLoggableError {
                analyticLoggableError.analyticsErrorType
            } else {
                Self.extractErrorType(from: self)
            }. // <= line 62 -------
        }()
        let errorCode: String = {
            if let analyticLoggableError = self as? AnalyticLoggableError {
                analyticLoggableError.analyticsErrorCode
            } else {
                Self.extractErrorCode(from: self)
            } // <= line 68 --------
        }()
        var params: [String: Any] = [
            "error_type": errorType,
            "error_code": errorCode,
        ]
        params["request_id"] = Self.extractStripeAPIRequestID(from: self)

        if let analyticLoggableError = self as? AnalyticLoggableError, !analyticLoggableError.additionalNonPIIErrorDetails.isEmpty {
            params["error_details"] = analyticLoggableError.additionalNonPIIErrorDetails
        }
        return params
    }


Based on what you have here, can you add some logging to determine which part of the if..else block is throwing the error?  That first if.. statement is doing a lot of work so unpacking it into separate steps might be helpful to debugging.  Based on the test of the error message, it seems like you aren't returning a String value in one of those conditions.

@RyanM The problem is that this is a generated swift code, I don't know how stripe is handling stuff on their part and I fear that I miss something with their code.
(I also do not write stripe, what should I do?)

@RyanM I fixed the file but an error in another file occurred! It seems like an error with stripe. How do you think I can fix it.

Please share the code you are writing.  The stripe generated code works wine in countless projects so I don't think it's something Stripe needs to fix (but I might be wrong). The wording of the error suggests you are not returning a String type value in some code path so you should share the code you are writing that causes this error to be thrown.

@RyanM downgrading to version less than 10.0.0 fixed the problem. I would also like to add that I tried the example from stripe repo and the same problem happened with me
